# Passing a value to a hidden form field / Parse data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, parsing

ok so clickpath has this phonenumber generator, it is unique per visitor or something like that. basically, its a dynamically generated phone number that pulls from a  .js file. a script is ran to display this #. what i need to do is grab this number off my site or from their script, and then insert it as a value for a hidden form field (each # is unique to an ad campaign, so id know if they came to the site organically, or through banners etc). i know how to submit values to a form field, but i cant figure out what function to call from their JS file OR how to strip the # from the div its displayed in or something.

Their Code

```
//** COPYRIGHT 2005-2006 - WhosCalling, Inc. **

//!!Do not change variable names!!

var CPMACCOUNTID='XXXXXX';
var CPMClientDir='XXXXXXXX';
var CPMPhoneNumber='XXXXXXXX';

var CPMUrl
if(location.protocol == 'https:'){
CPMUrl='https://analyticssl.clickpathmedia.com';
} else {
CPMUrl='http://analytics.clickpathmedia.com';
}

function RenderPhoneText(num, pat) {
document.write(GetOfficePhoneText(num, pat));
};

function RenderPhoneImage(num, dir) {
var CPMClientWebserver=document.domain; // Change this variable to your webserver        address ex: 'www.example.com'
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Sep1.gif" alt="-">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(0,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(1,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(2,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Sep2.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(3,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(4,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(5,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Sep3.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(6,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(7,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(8,1) + '.gif">');
  document.write('<img src="http://' + CPMClientWebserver +  '/' + dir + '/Number' + num.substr(9,1) + '.gif">');
};

function GetOfficePhoneText(num, pat) {
 var strResult = "";
  var intDigit = 0;

  for(var i=0;i<pat.length;++i){
    if (pat.charAt(i) == "N") {
    strResult = strResult + num.charAt(intDigit);
    intDigit = intDigit + 1;
}
else {
    strResult = strResult + pat.charAt(i);
}
 }

if (intDigit < 10) {
strResult = strResult + num.substr(intDigit);
  }

  return strResult;
};

function DisplayPhoneText(pat) {
//For backward compatibility
RenderPhoneText(CPMPhoneNumber,pat);
};

function DisplayPhoneImage(dir) {
//For backward compatibility
RenderPhoneImage(CPMPhoneNumber,dir);
};

function GetPhoneText(pat) {
//For flash compatibility
return GetOfficePhoneText(CPMPhoneNumber,pat);
};

function GetPhoneTextOffice(num, pat) {
//For flash compatibility
return GetOfficePhoneText(num,pat);
};

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="javascript" src="');
document.write(CPMUrl + '/JS/' + CPMClientDir + '/clickpathremote.js');
document.write('"><\/sc' + 'ript>');

document.write('<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="');
document.write('https://clicktotalk.whoscalling.com/makeClickToTalk.js');
document.write('"><\/sc' + 'ript>');

function clickToTalk(PhoneNumber)
{
makeClickToTalk('https://clicktotalk.whoscalling.com/', PhoneNumber,      CPGetSessionValue());
window.setTimeout('CPMLogTraffic(\'104\')', 2000);
}
```

My Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('clickphone').value = DisplayPhoneText("NNN.NNN.NNNN");
</script>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="clickphone" name="clickphone"/></input>
```

div the # is in

```
<div id="rightSide">
<script language="Javascript">DisplayPhoneText("NNN.NNN.NNNN");
</script>866.458.9533<noscript>866.303.5765</noscript>
<a href="" onclick="javascript:clickToTalk('8666180269'); return false;"><img src="images/click-to-call-button.png" border="0" alt="Click To Call"></a></div>
```

However, all this does is display the # again, and doesnt pass anything to the value=""

any ideas out there?

**UPDATE**

created the below functions, instead of document.write i used return to actually return the value.called in the return to my value and nothing...i think this stems from the fact this is a 3rd party script im toying with, and they are pulling in outside scripts i have no access to, hence the "don't change variable names" comment. i think the easiest thing at this point, would just be to parse out the phone number text inside the DIV. but i have no idea how to do that.

```
function RenderPhoneTextReturn(num, pat) {
  return(GetOfficePhoneText(num, pat));
};


function DisplayPhoneTextReturn(pat) {
    //For backward compatibility
    RenderPhoneTextReturn(CPMPhoneNumber,pat);
};

<script type="text/javascript">
document.onload=function() {
document.getElementById('clickphone').value = DisplayPhoneTextReturn("NNN.NNN.NNNN");
}
</script>
<input type="hidden" value="" id="clickphone" name="clickphone"/></input>
```

any help with this would be wonderful, as gaining clickpath "support" was a futile attempt. I literally had their "tech" tell me "this can be done, in theory, but we wont/cant help you." . GREAT tech team they have. youd think they would have some API support of some kind to help with this sort of thing.

Comment: any help here would be much appreciated! very frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the data you want is in a global variable named CPMPhoneNumber.  If you want that number unformatted, then you could probably just get away with:

```
document.getElementById('clickphone').value = CPMPhoneNumber;
```

If you want the formatted version of that number, then it looks like they provide you with a function named GetPhoneText() that receives the format you want.  You could call it like this:

```
document.getElementById('clickphone').value = GetPhoneText('NNN.NNN.NNNN');
```

I'd also advise against using document.onload for a number of reasons.  (For example, another script on the page might also be using document.onload and either your script or theirs would prevent the other one from running.)

If you happen to be using jQuery, then you can invoke the code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#clickphone").val(GetPhoneText('NNN.NNN.NNNN'));
    });
</script>
```

Or, if you're not using jQuery, then at the very least you could avoid having to use document.onload by placing your script tag directly below the hidden field, ensuring that it doesn't get invoked until after the field has been added to the DOM:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="clickphone" name="clickphone"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('clickphone').value = GetPhoneText('NNN.NNN.NNNN');
</script>
```

Comment: brilliant thanks! im new to this and sometimes i just need a little direction. its working as intended!. also thanks for the pointer on document.onload!